# Set state causes another modal to open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, antd

I'm struggle with my Ant design modal component. The component visibility is set on local state. On this modal i have to choose the payment method using the follow code:

```
setPayment(object){

        let totalPrice = this.props.activeSell.fields.total_price.value.toFixed(2)

        let tempState = {
            fields:{
                totalValue:{
                    value: totalPrice
                },
                receiveValue:{
                    value: (object.id == 2 || object.id == 3) ? totalPrice : '' 
                },
                change:{
                    value: '0.00'
                },
            },
            isreceiveValue: (object.id == 2 || object.id == 3) ? true : false,
            visible: true,
            payment: object
        }

        this.setState({ state: Object.assign(this.state,tempState)});
...
```

But instead of setting the payment method on the current modal, another modal takes place in front. When i finish and close my modal, i have to close another (The first).

I want just set state and keep one openi modal. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: are both modals using `this.state.visible` to indicate they are open?

Comment: I have only one Modal, but the same modal opens twice.

<Modal  ... visible={this.state.visible}...>      
...Content...
</Modal>

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```js
this.setState({
  state: Object.assign({}, this.state, tempState)
});
```

Comment: I tried like this. The Modal component not update. the component stay static when its expected to change with payment values and information.